# Azure Data Factory user parameter

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

In Azure Databricks I want to get the user that trigger manually a Notebook in Data Factory pipeline. I think Data Factory doesn't have a dynamic parameter to pass the user to Databricks, only pipeline features and functions. Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It does have dynamic parameters for a databricks notebook!! Follow this tutorial and it will guide you to do just that :D

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook

Hope this helped!